# Get the rollback information of a changeset

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

as it's described in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfspowertools/thread/605d6c6c-2acf-4567-8c50-b4a4d6303d3d);

I installed tfs power tools 2012. I used rollback feature by selecting the changeset: thus I'm expecting to rollback to that version and it's working great. When I look at the history of the file that was rollbacked at the "Change" column it's written "edit, rollback"; which is cool.

However I cannot see "which version it has been rollback to". So before rollback I can select the version but later on when I wanted to see "which version it has been rollback to" I can't. Is there a way to find out that information?

Answer (score 0):

Rollback is non destructive so rollback will undo the checkin ( change set ) and then the previous change set is checked in as a normal checkin. There is no reall reason to differentiate between a rolled back checkin and a normal one.