# How can I determine what changeset was rolled back in TFS 2012?

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2012

In TFS 2012, when I rollback a changeset, a new changeset is created for the corresponding "undo" changes.  However, if I look at the history, there is no indication of what changeset was rolled back (there's no link, etc.).  Is there a way to tell from looking at a changeset that it was rolling back another changeset (and what that changeset was)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the rollback information of a changeset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310501/get-the-rollback-information-of-a-changeset)

Comment: I wouldn't say its an exact duplicate, as I'm not asking what version it was rolled back to, but just which changeset was undone.  In any case, it doesn't sound there is any association.

Comment: Would it not have just rolled back `n-1`?

Comment: No, changeset numbers are unique across a team project, if not a team project collection.  Rolling back changeset 1234 could result in a new changeset 5432.  Also, rolling back a changeset does not necessarily roll back other changesets which occurred afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the other question linked by Betty and what I'm seeing in TFS, it does not look like there is any association to the changeset which is being rolled back.  I will start following a convention that each checkin comment for a rollback will contain the changeset being rolled back.